# Android gradle import lots of errors and trouble

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

Im trying to get used to this new gradle system built into the new Android studio.

I've tried a really basic task, to import the websockets library into my project. So I imported the module via the normal route (File->Project Structure), I imported the java-websockets module in and added it as a dependency too. Finally I import the org.java_websockets class into my project.

My project ended up looking like this:

[image]

So this is where my problem starts, I give it a shot and try to build it and run into the usual gradle errors. So I added an 'include' line to my settings.gradle

```
include ':java-ws-client'
```

and another one into my build.gradle

```
compile project(':java-ws-client')
```

So now I find myself stuck with two problems:

One fairly undescriptive one:

[image]

and another:

[image]

I've tried updating my android studio to the latest one, and the project above is a fresh one.

How can I avoid pulling my hair out?

Comment: Can you try to compile from the command line and see if this works? At this point, it could be an issue with the Gradle integration in Studio or in Gradle. Compiling from the command line helps narrowing it down. Also, you should never change dependencies through the Project Structure dialog (for now)

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, settings.gradle is inside TestProjectProject, which makes TestProjectProject a root project. However, java-ws-client is parallel TestProjectProject, which is outside of TestProjectProject's scope. You cannot reference any project outside its scope using ":foobar" notation.

To fix the second problem, you should either move java-ws-client into TestProjectProject, or declare java-ws-client as an external dependency, and add proper repository resolver to find it.

To fix the first problem, make sure in TestProjectProject/build.gradle you have applied the [Java plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html#N103C6). The Java plugin creates the "default" configuration.